# x axis domain issue in D3 Line chart

Tags: charts, d3.js, line

I have drawn a Line chart in D3. I am facing issue in x axis alignment.Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sk2Cf/)

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

    x.domain(dataset.map(function(d) { 
        return d.qName; }));
```

The issue is -"points and the x-axis aren't on the same level". (there's some shift visible)).
How can i shift Q1 to intersection point of x-axis and Y axis.
Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the height by adjusting the translation of the group that contains the axis, e.g. change the value `height` in

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
```

You may want to try `(height-20)` for example.